# Understanding a SQL error handling script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling

I'm brand new to SQL and I'm trying to understand the following script.
could someone break this down for me?

```
ErrorHandler:   
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RAISERROR('Error occurred in script to update version: transaction rolled back', 182, 4)
END
ELSE
COMMIT
```

I have knowledge of Java, so I understand for loops.
It's the SQL syntax that I need help with.

1. For example, what does the double @ symbol represent?
2. ROLLBACK TRANSACTION - these are SQL reserved keywords?
3. What does ELSE COMMIT mean?

Thank you, 
Ray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stucture of the block is as follows:

```
IF @@ERROR <> 0 
BEGIN 
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
  RAISERROR('Error occurred in script to update version: transaction rolled back',  182, 4) 
END 
ELSE 
  COMMIT
```

So this is a basic condition written in t-sql (no relation with java :)).
The `BEGIN` and `END` tokens are just delimiters, and are used just like `{` and `}` in java - that's why they are used in the IF branch (two commands) and are not used in the else branch (a single command - not mandatory)

The @@Error (and other variables begining with @@, like @@ROWCOUNT) are system variables. [@@Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933181%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) specifically contains the last error code given by a command, and it is checked in the snippet to see if everything went OK.

If there are errors, two actions are taken
  - a [ROLLBACK TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx) command is issued, reversing all changes made to the database (since the last BEGIN TRANSACTION)
  - an [error is raised](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) no notify the caller of the abnormal termination of the code.

Here the constants (182 and 4) are used for the parameters of the RaiseError call @severity and @state. I suspect that the 182 is a typo, because @severity should be a number in the 0-25 range, and (by convention) 18 is used for a "high severity user error". The @state param is just some data you can add to the call, to help distinguish between multiple error messages.

If there are no errors, a single [COMMIT TRANSACTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190295.aspx) is issued, that makes all changes (since the last BEGIN TRANSACTION) permanent and available to all other users of the data.

Answer (score 5):

1. @@ indicates server-side variables. Think of them as the SQL equivalent of a `$var` in a client-side script.
2. ROLLBACK indicates that when the error occurs, the DB server should "undo" the current transaction - basically drop any changes performed up until the error occured. e.g in a bank transaction where you transfer money from account #1 to account #2, if something goes wrong with the deposit to #2, you "undo" the withdrawal from #1 so the money doesn't simply vanish because of the error.
3. ELSE COMMIT simply means "make it so".

In pseudo-code:

```
if (something went wrong) {
   undo all operations performed since the transaction started;
   send out an error message
} else {
   save the operations and commit them to disk
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the analogy, Marc!

Answer (score 2):

@@ERROR will hold the error number, if it is not 0 an error occurred
It is best practice to store that in a variable because any action will reset it to 0, same applies for @@rowcount, see here: [When should you store @@ROWCOUNT into a variable?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/when-can-you-grab-rowcount-into-a-variab)

So if it is not 0 the script rolls back any work, if it is 0 it commits the transaction

commit means, the changes are persisted, rollback means the changes are reverted to the state before the transaction started

Start here to get more information http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html

Comment: I'm not sure whether the OP understands the meaning of `rolls back` and `commits the transaction` because he asked what that means.

Answer (score 0):

`@@Error` is a special value in SQL Server that contains the error number of the error that occurred on the last statement executed (or in this case, the statement prior to the Goto ErrorHandler label). If it's zero, the last statement executed successfully.

`Rollback Transaction` (and it's matching `Commit`) are technically part of the SQL lexicon. They are ensuring that if an error has occurred to rollback the current transaction. That means all of the database changes that have occurred in the script will be reverted as if they had never taken place or if no error has occurred (because `@@Error = 0`), those changes will be persisted into the database.

[RAISERROR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)

Comment: That's what I was looking for, Thomas. Thank you... if you don't mind, could you answer this as well? A few lines above, I saw this line "RAISERROR(@ErrorMsg,14,2)"

Where does the developer get these number 14 and 2?

Thanks,

Comment: @Ray - I've posted the BOL (Books Online) link for Raiserror. 14 is the severity. It determines, for example, whether SQL Server should shut down or just the current statement should fail. Why your particular script decided on 14 is its own mystery. The "2" is the "State" argument. Why your script chose "2" is yet another mystery.

Comment: Much appreciated. I checked out the link and I have a much better understanding of severity and state levels. I do agree with you and I'm puzzled why the original developer chose '2'. But for this discussion, I guess it's irrelevant.